# Enable debug to show values in the flowchart editor

Tags: debugging, cryengine

I am starting to learn to use CryEngine V, and have found documentation lacking, in some aspects.

Following [the initial game logic tutorials](https://www.cryengine.com/tutorials/designer-series/game-logic), I observe the instructor selecting "debug" from the menu. The flow chart instantly comes to life, displaying all of the values going in and out of each function.

Unfortunately, when I follow this instruction, nothing happens. Clicking on the "debug" button results in no apparent action. I have looked around for further instructions, but all I can find is the general assumption that it will just work, without any additional action. As you can see from my recording, this assumption is not accurate to my situation.

[image: Selecting "debug" has no reaction what so ever.]

Without this working, it is rather difficult to even know if I am following the flowchart creation process properly. How do I enable visual debug in the flowchart editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the tutorials describe "running debug" while simply selecting the button, it appears they are taking additional steps off-screen.

Selecting "debug" does not display debug information as is shown in the tutorials. You still must run the game, either directly, or through enabling physics and AI.